# Import/refresh automatically a CSV file ? Powershell or not?

Tags: list, powershell, import, refresh, csv

I have to import a CSV file into a list (put it in a tab). But this CSV will be updated (weel, in fact it will be regenerated), and I need SharePoint to refresh the list with new data.

I don't know if I must use Powershell or if there is an alternative way to do this.

And I don't know  the frequency of refreshing, but I guess this is not the current problem.

Thanks in advance.

Nico

Comment: I'm currently having a look at [this](http://davidlozzi.com/2012/02/29/loading-sharepoint-lists-from-excel/), and I think it is exactly what I want. Im testing it and come back for my feeling. Then I think I will have to use timer job.

Comment: as an alternate solution you can also edit your list in datasheet view and copy paste your columns from excel directly.

Comment: @Ashish I'm not sure I understand what you mean. With powershell, I'm now able to create the list if it doesn't exist. I'm looking for a way, to remove all items in my list, and put my new ones I get from the csv.

Comment: for deleting items you need to write another powershell script or include the delete logic in existing powerhsell.if you want I can give you the powershell to delete the items.

Comment: Find it with `$ListItems = $list.Items;$count =$ListItems.Count - 1;for($intIndex = $count; $intIndex -gt -1; $intIndex--){$ListItems.Delete($intIndex)}` Now I need to delete at the creation the Field "Title", and show all other fields I create with my script

Comment: Script is done. To hide the Title default link, its name is "LinkTitle", get from the default view : `$view = $web.GetViewFromUrl($list.DefaultViewUrl)`, then `$view.ViewFields.Delete("LinkTitle")`. This should help. And in order to add a column : `$view.ViewFields.Add`. Let me know if someone has another question/problem.